# Facebook scraper doesn't work after disabling SSLv3 (sslv3 alert handshake failure)

Tags: facebook, apache, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-javascript-sdk

I disabled SSLv3 on my server to protect users from the POODLE vulnerability, but since doing so Facebook's scraper no longer works on my sites (so sharing pages on facebook doesn't result in a share image, title, or description being pulled in).

When I try using [the debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) with [a URL](https://www.pricewombat.com/product/109955/Destiny-Standard-Edition-Xbox-360), it shows this error:

> Curl Error : SSL_CONNECT_ERROR error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I have been Googling and searching on here, but haven't been able to find much information on this.

Do I have to keep SSLv3 enabled in order to share pages on Facebook?

Comment: I ran your domain through several SSL checkers, and weirdly https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/ complains that you had neither TLS v1.0, TLS v1.1 nor TLS v1.2 enabled. Since other checkers are not reporting this (and Chrome says TLS v1.2 is used as well when I visit the site), one might suspect it to be an error of this particular tool – but since you’re having trouble with the FB scraper as well, it might indicate that there _is_ something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: @CBroe The SSL configuration did indeed seem to be the problem. I reset the settings to default and the facebook scraper started working again. Would you like to make your comment an answer? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, no problem. By resetting stuff to defaults, do you mean that you had to enable SSLv3 again? Or was it something else that was not “default”, and now it works with SSLv3 still disabled?

Comment: @CBroe When I disabled SSLv3 I think I copy/pasted a cipher string and protocol configuration string from a cpanel WHM wiki page and it must have been wrong or outdated. I just reset the values to default in WHM, which by now defaults to SSLv3 being disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your domain through several SSL checkers, and weirdly [sslcheck.globalsign.com](https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/) complains that you had neither TLS v1.0, TLS v1.1 nor TLS v1.2 enabled.

Since other checkers are not reporting this (and Chrome says TLS v1.2 is used as well when I visit the site), one might suspect it to be an error of this particular tool – but since you’re having trouble with the FB scraper as well, it might indicate that there *is* something wrong with your configuration.